# converting to key, values pair

Tags: javascript

My question

1. How to read rom txt file in JS
2. Best approach to process the data. Something like this below or ????

   ```
   var data = [
   {
     name: "Orange",
     type: "Fruit",
     desc: "some description about the recipe"
   },
     {
     name: "Spinach",
     type: "Veg",
     desc: "some description about the recipe"
   },
     {
     name: "Beans",
     type: "Veg",
     desc: "some description about the recipe"
   },
   ```

   ]

I want to have an object array so that I can process it further to print out unique names of fruits, just veggies and just fruits.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using AJAX and then a regular expression.

If you're using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'someTextFile.txt',
    success: function(data) {
        var regEx = /([a-zA-Z]+), ([a-zA-Z]+).*[\r\n  \t]*([a-zA-Z0-9 \.]+)/g,
            recipe, allRecipies = [];
        while (recipe = rege.exec(data)) {
            allRecipies.push({
                name: recipe[1],
                type: recipe[2],
                desc: recipe[3],
            });
        }
        console.log(allRecipies);
    }
});
```

If you're not using jQuery

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       data = xhttp.responseText;
        var regEx = /([a-zA-Z]+), ([a-zA-Z]+).*[\r\n  \t]*([a-zA-Z0-9 \.]+)/g,
            recipe, allRecipies = [];
        while (recipe = rege.exec(data)) {
            allRecipies.push({
                name: recipe[1],
                type: recipe[2],
                desc: recipe[3],
            });
        }
        console.log(allRecipies);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "filename", true);
xhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother creating your own parser to read in formats.

Save your content in a standard data-interchange format like [json](http://www.json.org/) or [xml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)

There are so many others and lookup standard libraries to parse them and get your information.

I'll recommend json, as Javascript as a `JSON` object for parsing JSON Files. And their are other good libraries for parsing JSON.

Comment: Are you running on node, if yes .. node as a native JSON.parse .. try that.

Comment: I am just trying to do in Vanilla JS

Comment: Yea, I understand, I mean are you running this script in your browser or on nodejs?

Comment: In my browser as I dont have much experience using node.js

Comment: Okay, just simply pass in promotions to JSON.parse() function. 

Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript